How to display function docstrings on mouse hover in *Completions* buffer
In Emacs, when I use M-x followed by typing the beginning of a function name and then press TAB, I get the *Completions* buffer showing a list of possible function candidates for completion.
I would like to enhance this process by displaying the function's documentation string (docstring) when I hover over a function name in the *Completions* buffer using the mouse.
E.g,, if I have this three functions:
(defun my-func-add (a b)
  "Add two numbers A and B and return the result."
  (interactive)
  (+ a b))

(defun my-func-subtract (a b)
  "Subtract B from A and return the result."
  (interactive)
  (- a b))

(defun my-func-multiply (a b)
  "Multiply two numbers A and B and return the result."
  (interactive)
  (* a b))

I'd like the my-func-add's  docstring to be displayed when I hover over it's function name in the Completions* buffer using the mouse.

I would prefer the docstring to be displayed in the same way as when I hover over an item in the mode-line. E.g.:

Is there an existing way to achieve this functionality, or could it be implemented using existing packages or configurations?

Does this question help?

It helps, thank you. I'm now considering Eldoc.
